# JQuery enabling a textbox with a button event query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, textbox

I have a tiny issue if anybody can help... I am trying to implement a form, so when the page loads the textbox is disabled. If the user wishes to amend information they first have to press a button which will enable the text box.

```
<input id="text" type="text" disabled="disabled">
<br />
<button>Enable</button
```

So I have a basic textbox which is disabled. Then an event that should enable the textbox...

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript">   
     $(document).ready(function(){     
       $("button").click(function(){         
        $("#text").attr("disabled","false");     
       });   
     });   
  </script>
```

I can get this working when the textbox is not initially disabled and I want to disable it, though I can not get it working the other way round - when it is disabled and I want to enable it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have created a jsfiddle for you see the working example...

you should use **removeAttr** instead of **attr**
code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){     
       $("button").click(function(){         
        $("#text").removeAttr("disabled");     
       });   
     });
```

link:-http://jsfiddle.net/L7S37/15/

Answer (score 1):

You are giving boolean value as String

Use this

```
$("#text").attr("disabled",false);
```

instead of

```
$("#text").attr("disabled","false");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/11/)

Comment: Thank you for your time, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this, Even the last answer by Mr Soni is correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $("button").click(function(){         
    $("#text").prop('disabled', false);     
   });   
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time all comments have been appreciated